# how to point apache to different version of php

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I installed apache on ubuntu like so:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

I initially had installed PHP by doing:

```
apt-get install php5
```

That gave me php 5.3.x. Now I want to use the latest version php 5.4.x so I installed from source. Through the cli

```
$ php -v
```

outputs the correct version PHP 5.4.3

When I run `phpinfo()` through the web, I still get php5.3.x. How would I point apache to use my newly installed php instead?

Comment: either you didn't restart apache or you only installed the cli version of php not the apache module version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hook" happens when you're about to compile PHP.

```
$ which apx2
```

If there is no output, run

```
$ apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev
$ which apx2
```

copy the location that the 'which' command gave you. While inside the php source, run

```
$ ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

replacing /usr/bin/apxs2 with the location on your clipboard. Restart apache and it should be ready to go!

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in a vhost config:

```
AddHandler php-cgi-script .php
Action php-cgi-script /php5/php5-cgi
```

The accompanying php module configuration would be:

```
ScriptAlias /php5 /usr/bin
<Directory /usr/bin/>
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

I don't know exactly how it would fit in your setup, so you need to improvise a bit.

Also, a very big beware: there was a huge [security bug](http://eindbazen.net/2012/05/php-cgi-advisory-cve-2012-1823/) in PHP CGI. Test if it effects you.

Comment: I would like to be able to use the latest php without much configuration. Much like doing apt-get install requires very little configuration.